# Action can't be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Apologies for vague title. I am following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#cha-beginning tutorial to learn RoR on cloud9. I have made the changes in my controller as listed in chapter 1, heading 1.4

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
    render text: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

and my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

But when i restart the server, I gett error

```
Started GET "/" for 69.157.46.139 at 2015-12-03 21:20:46 +0000

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'hello' could not be found for ApplicationController):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/unknown_action.html.erb within rescues/layout (9.6ms)


Started GET "/" for 69.157.46.139 at 2015-12-03 21:21:46 +0000

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'hello' could not be found for ApplicationController):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/unknown_action.html.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)
```

I have already tried `root to: 'application#hello'` and it still didn't work

Comment: try adding `match "/" => "application#hello"` in the routes before you set the root. See if this works

Comment: What happens if you do `rake routes` in your terminal? Can you post what you get?

Comment: The ApplicationController is in the file `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` right?

Comment: @Saurabh doing `match "/" => "application#hello"` gives me error that i shouldn't use `match without specifying HTTP method`

Answer (score 0):

The application controller is not for defining actions. This is the base controller where likely other controllers should inherit behavior/properties from. You should create another controller and define hello there.

### using generator

`rails g controller Welcome hello`

### routes file

`root Welcome#hello`

`get 'hello' => 'welcome#hello'`

### app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def hello

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. The problem is with Cloud9 IDE. I did save the `application_controller` after creating the `hello` method but IDE wasn't saving it untill i explicitly clicked on `File > Save`. I figured it out when i `cat application_Controller.rb` and noticed that `hello` method doesn't exist there.